# How to generate .lib files using dlltool on Windows 10?

Tags: fftw, .lib

I want to install the FFTW library in my system which is running on Windows 10. My compiler is minGW GCC 10.1 and I am using Code Blocks.

I have downloaded the 64-bit version fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip from http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html and then opened the command window as adminstrator and set my directory to the bin folder of the mingw64 so that I can run dlltool.

However, when I type the command `dlltool -d libfftw3-3.def` I am getting the error `dlltool: Can't open def file: libfftw3-3.def`

I guess this is happening because the libfftw3-3.def file is inside the FFTW folder and cannot be seen by the dlltool. Is that right? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason seems to be rather obvious. As I wrote in my question the files libfftw3-3.def, libfftw3f-3.def and libfftw3l-3.def are located inside the FFTW folder (wherever might that be in your case). I copied an pasted them inside the bin folder of the mingw64 compiler and then executed the following commands:

`dlltool -d libfftw3-3.def`
`dlltool -l libfftw3-3.lib`

Then repeated the process for the other two .def files.